# Java: Trying to compare two groups of strings, each with a few thousand tiny individual strings

Tags: java, string, compare, string-comparison

Title says what I'm trying to do. I have two groups of strings: group 15 and group 12. I'm trying to find the strings that are present in both groups. I tried making two string arrays and copy and pasting each group into its own array, but java is saying "code is too large" when I try to compile. If I remember correctly, there is a 64,000 byte limit for a method? Is there a way I can take my two lists of strings and scan them and tell me which strings are in both groups without exceeding the code size limit? Is there a way I can put each group into a text file and then input that text file into the code somehow so it doesn't surpass the limit?

Comment: You should try to post a code snippet and try to explain what you're doing. See this link [[ask]]. You could try to push your string groups into text files, read from them and implement your logic. Is this a home work problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read  [ask] to learn how to ask a good, answerable and on-topic questions that contains all the informations needed to provide an answer.

Comment: i never heard of/touched the "code size limit" (but believe you ... 64kbyte is a "huge method")..."Is there a way" - hundreds! I would align with the given format(and requirement), where do you have these strings from? typed em?

Comment: ...bring the strings into files (with a simple but distinct format. eg. comma or line separated ...simplest: 1 word/line)   ...then you can read the files from code, and process them accordingly (comma/line wise) ..a more flexible solution (like seen at hackerrank et al.): Use a "console scanner" in your algorithm..then you can feed it  manualy/via user input or via (os) script/"pipe".

Comment: .."algorithmically" it sounds like you *have to* load one file (the smaller one) completely into memory, while the second(bigger) file can be processed "buffered"...